# How do I use optional attributes to select articles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

```
#routes.rb
get "/:year(/:month(/:day))(/:genre)" => "archives#index", :constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/ }

#archives_controller.rb
def index
@articles = Article.all(params[:year, :month, :day, :genre],:order => "created_at DESC")
```

I want to be able to get the articles by year, or year and month, or year and month and day, with genre optionally on the end of any of those. Can I do this in one statement or do I need if blocks? Also I want to be able to get all the articles in a specific genre, but I think I need to do that in a separate action? Thanks!

UPDATE

I ended up using the metawhere gem plus a method to build my date:

```
def index
  date_builder
  @articles = Article.where(:created_at.matches % @date, :genre.matches % @genre).order("created_at DESC")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @articles }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
    format.html
  end
end

def date_builder
  @date = ""
  @date += params[:year] if !(params[:year].nil?)
  @date += "-" + params[:month] if !(params[:month].nil?)
  @date += "-" + params[:day] if !(params[:day].nil?)
  @date += "%"
end
```

This reduced the number of sql calls to one and make everything look pretty. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has_scope` gem to define some scopes to be applied to your collection if there're matching params in the request. You can find [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) here.

Other alternative could be the `meta-where` and `meta-search` gems. You can find an explanation on how to use them [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
@articles = Article.where(:year => params[:year], :month => params[:month]).order("created_at DESC")
@articles = @articles.where(:day => params[:day]) if params[:day]
@articles = @articles.where(:genre => params[:genre]) if params[:genre]
```

Comment: I started with something like this but it wasn't DRY enough